# Pandas find cell based on month of datetime multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

The result of:

```
groups = merge.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='dt', freq='M'), 'rate']).sum()
```

Is:

```
                 consumption
dt         rate             
2017-11-30 flat  203688000.0
2017-12-31 flat  217094000.0
2018-01-31 flat  265193000.0
2018-02-28 flat  184570000.0
2018-03-31 flat  160481000.0
2018-04-30 flat  178990000.0
2018-05-31 flat  167311000.0
2018-06-30 flat  178714000.0
2018-07-31 flat  262210000.0
2018-08-31 flat  198391000.0
2018-09-30 flat  189134000.0
2018-10-31 flat  186050000.0
```

Now I can access consumption for a particular dt/rate like so:

```
groups.loc[(date, rate)]['consumption']
```

But I'm having trouble writing my `loc` so that I can find a column based on the *month* and the rate.

I've tried using:

```
groups.loc[groups['dt'].month == month.month & groups['rate'] == k]['consumption']
```

But I get `KeyError` because `dt` and `rate` are indices.

Is there a way to do this? Or perhaps modify the `groupby` so it gives me a month index instead?

Comment: What type of values are in your `dt` column?  datetime.date values or pandas timestamps?

Comment: pandas timestamps.

Comment: Did you want values just based on `month`, or both `month` and `year`?

Comment: Just month. The year is the part causing the issue, which is why I want to go to just month (since I know I'll only have 12 months anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC.`get_level_values`

```
df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values(0).month == 11) & (df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'flat')]['consumption']
Out[1814]: 
dt          rate
2017-11-30  flat    203688000.0
Name: consumption, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This returns a `Series` like: `[dt          rate
2018-07-31  flat    262210000.0
Name: consumption, dtype: float64]`, how do I just get the `consumption` value?

Comment: add `.values[0][0]` on the end of that statement

Comment: Actually needed `.values[0]`, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.